# Deriving from a class only to provide a special constructor

Tags: c#, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, language-agnostic, inheritance

In our codebase, I encountered the following construct: There is a base class B, and then there is a class D which derives from B, but does not override or add any members. In fact, D is completely empty - except for a constructor that initializes some (inherited) properties in a special way.

Consider this contrived C# example:

```
public class Angle
{
  public Angle(float degrees)
  {
    Degrees = degrees;
  }

  public float Degrees { get; set; }
}

public class RightAngle : Angle
{
  public RightAngle() : base(90)
  {
  }
}
```

To me, this seems like a gross violation of OOP principles, but I cannot really pinpoint the issue. Is this a proper use of inheritance or a bad idea? Should I replace the derived class with -for example- a static factory?

Comment: related: [Is inheritance that adds rules bad?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/238386/31260) _'Maybe the point an old professor of me once made is correct: "you should only ever use inheritance to overload the constructor". At the time that seemed a bit strict but now...'_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While mildly distasteful, this sort of thing isn't the worst thing in the world. It doesn't explictly violate any OO principles.

My main complaint is that with *just* the code above, not all right angles are `RightAngle`s, though using value semantics would solve that.

Personally, I would work to make the class immutable and then simply have a static readonly instance of `Angle.RightAngle` or similar.

Comment: My complaint on the presented code is that a `RightAngle` doesn't necessarily represent a right angle (as you can change the inherited Degrees property)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the inheritance approach taken here in your question is to only guarantee that the object creation happens in a whole by appropriately setting the mandatory attributes of the class, if the proper object creation is the sole purpose then i would suggest object [Builder patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) instead of going with the inheritance approach.